# How to bind to a resource sys:Double?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am very new in stackoverflow. I hope here, I will find an answer. My Problem: I created a user control. In resources there is

`<sys:Double x:Key="BRadiusX" >5</sys:Double>`

In control Template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Ellipse"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                               RadiusX="{DynamicResource BRadiusX}"
                               RadiusY="{DynamicResource BRadiusY}">.....
```

Now I want to bind the 5 to
a DependancyProperty in Code:

```
public static DependencyProperty BorderRadiusXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderRadiusX", typeof(double), typeof(MySlider1),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(5.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    [Category("Thumb"), Description("XRadius of border round the thumb")]
    public double BorderRadiusX
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderRadiusXProperty); }


        set { SetValue(BorderRadiusXProperty, value); }
    }
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Many thanks forwarding

Answer (score 0):

In code (constructor for instance), you can :

```
double radius = (double)Resources["BRadiusX"]
```

Then you can :

```
BorderRadiusX = radius;
```

It is not really a databinding, it is only ressource look up.
If you need databinding, it 's more complicated but for a double that is immutable I am not sure it 's useful to make databinding.

Resources is a property of the Application or FrameworkElements like Windows, UserControls, Grid.

Regards

Comment: Good Idea! The code is part of a slider UserControl. Iam using the controltemplate to change Thumb etc. When installed in an App you should be able to change some settings in the property Window of the usercontrol.  But in this way it always changes back to "5" or whatever you prefix in resources. Any further idea.

Comment: I wrote it in answer No 02. I am not yet quiet used to all things here. You can see it above your answer. regards

Answer (score 0):

```
 public MySlider1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Resources["BRadiusX"] = BorderRadiusX;
        Resources["BRadiusY"] = BorderRadiusY;
    }

   protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        Resources["BRadiusX"] = BorderRadiusX;
        Resources["BRadiusY"] = BorderRadiusY;
    }

    public static DependencyProperty BorderRadiusXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderRadiusX", typeof(double), typeof(MySlider1),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(5.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    [Category("Thumb"), Description("XRadius of border round the thumb")]
    public double BorderRadiusX
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderRadiusXProperty); }


        set { SetValue(BorderRadiusXProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty BorderRadiusYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderRadiusY", typeof(double), typeof(MySlider1),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(5.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    [Category("Thumb"), Description("YRadius of border round the thumb")]
    public double BorderRadiusY
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderRadiusYProperty); }


        set { SetValue(BorderRadiusYProperty, value); }
    }
```